# import top 40 data from internet in a MS Access table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I try to download the top 40 from  https://www.top40.nl/top40/2017/week-14 but I don't get any further than the 1 big bunch of data with all the top 40 records in a record. Can anyone help me with the correct code to fetch this data? I just neet the position, artist and songtitle.

This is what I have so far.

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim dd As Variant


Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate "https://www.top40.nl/top40/2017/week-14"

Do While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

dd = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("top40")(0).InnerText

Set IE = Nothing
Set objElement = Nothing
Set objCollection = Nothing
```

[image HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voSc9.jpg)

Comment: can you show the html rather than the link pls.

Comment: I added an image of part of the code

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Dim Element As IHTMLElement
Dim i As integer
Dim artist as String
Dim position As Integer
For i=0 To  IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("top40")(3).Children.Length
       position = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("top40")(0).Children(i).Children(0).innertext
       artist = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("top40")(3).Children(i).Children(2).Children(3).Children(1).Children(1).innertext 
Next i
```

And for the album name I let you deduct it the same way :)

Explanation :

1) Why ("top40")(3) -> `MsgBox IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("top40").length` returns 4 which means that there is not one unique element with that classname, so to select the right one you can for example do this :

```
For i = 0 to IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("top40").length
MsgBox IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("top40")(i).tagname 'you'll only get one with the OL tagname which is the last one (4th element but index 3)
Next i
```

2) Then to go through the elements proceed as the following (this is one way out of multiple ways to do it and I am not saying it is the best one) :

- In the inspector, click on the little arrow which allows you to select any element on the page -> You select for example the name of the artist of the first position -> This will show you its bit of HTML code.
- From the form "top40" until this specific element you can then navigate through the children or childnodes also. Learn to use the Watch window in order to go through the different elements. Children(3) means the 4th children for example.

Let me know if you need more details on this.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work? I got a type mismatch on `position =` and `artist =`... I was about to write my own solution (but yours looks much better) - maybe I missing a reference or something?

Comment: No not yet. but I got some information. You have to make a reference to microsoft HTML object libary and microsoft internet controls. Let me know if you get it working and where it goes wrong? I'l keep on trying too :-)

Comment: Yes those references are required. Tell me if something goes wrong (line + message). I wrote it without trying it but it should work.

Comment: Ohh ok just checked it by curiosity. Thing is that there are 4 elements with the classname "top40" so I didn't choose the right one. I modified my solution and tried it. It works now.

Comment: The artist line works great now, but the position does not. Can you explain how the children(i).children(2).... works? I'm all new at at that :-)?

Comment: Position should also be `("top40")(3)` but this is really cool stuff @Seb

Comment: Indeed great stuff. I Thought I understood and tried to extract "/ed-sheeran-12/shape-of-you-1-28465" but now way Can you help me with that one? :-( At least I managed to get the songtitle.

Comment: you mean the code doesn't work for you or you don't understand it ?